# QT: further "Plumbing" for Model->View->Delegate

Tags: qt

I have a QListView, clearly showing, My model is full of data. My model’s ::rowCount() is called and returns a > 0 result. I connected my model to the QListView with “setModel”. I connected the delegate to the QListView with “setItemDelegate”.

Yet the “Paint” method on my delegate isn’t called, not once. Not even after resizing the live QListView. Why?

Do I need further “hooking up” of events here? perhaps connecting some slots to signals? I thought the “setModel” and “setDelegate” will take care of that for me. Was I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it.
I wasn’t signaling of a model update using the model’s “begin/end” method pairs. I was adding content to the model using my own methods so the model really could not notify the listView there’s content to view which of course resulted in no painting.

Comment: A good step to validate models is to use ModelTest: http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/Model_Test